# How can I change value of Global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

Default variable set `var a = ''; var b = ''; var html =' <td>'+a+b+'</td>'`;

then I create another event use ajax

```
$('element').click(function(){
....

         //when ajax was success  change value of variable 
         a = 'webb';
         b = 'sam';
         // And append the variable "html"
         $(div).append(html );
```

but the variable a & b is empty. why??

Comment: I personally do not see any AJAX here, just a click handler. Does the handler even get called? In addition, are you aware of that if you change your `a` and `b`, your `html` won't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have assigned "html" variable value of "<td> + a + b + </td>" when a & b were empty and then never changed it.
Try:

```
     a = 'webb';
     b = 'sam';
     // And append the variable "html"
     html =' <td>'+a+b+'</td>'
     $(div).append(html);
```

Just to give some clarity: this is not related with variables being global or local. You get empty "`<td></td>`" because variable "html" is assigned a *value* (i.e. it get's normal string value rather than a reference to a and b variables).